# ajax cascading dropdown list method error 500 on IE10

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, asp.net-ajax, asmx, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm developing an application in asp.net which needs cascading dropdown lists to be filled by calling asmx methods.

The code works fine on Google Chrome and Mozilla FireFox but throws **Method Error 500** on IE10..
Is there any IE setting I'm missing??

Here is the code:

```
<ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="SomeCascadingDropDown" runat="server"
ParentControlID="SomeParentDropDownList" Category="Product"
TargetControlID="SomeDropDownList"
ServicePath="~/Services/SomeEntitysData.asmx"
ServiceMethod="GetSomeEntity"
LoadingText="Loading"
PromptText="Select">
</ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
```

e

Comment: That is unlikely since webservice suppose to be platform independent. Please add more code such as those codebehind for webservice

Answer (score 1):

// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]